# erroneous function in function: r.squaredGLMM is not able to take over arguments in function

Tags: r, function, glm

I have trouble with embedding a function in another function I am about to write. The particular function that shows some misbehaviour (or at least, it seems so to me), is the `r.squaredGLMM` function. It works fine on its own, but when called within the function I am writing, there is an error happening that I, honestly, do not understand. Here comes some example data:

```
library (lme4)
library (MuMIn)

my_table <- data.frame ("type" = c (rep ("low", 15), rep ("mid", 15), rep ("high", 15)),
                        "group" = rep (c ("A", "B", "C"),5),
                        "dependent" = sort (rpois (45, 3)),
                        "var_A" = rnorm (45),
                        "var_B" = c (rnorm (15), rnorm (15, 6, 0.1), rnorm (15, 18, 2)),
                        "var_C" = rep (c(3,1,6,2,8,2,1,6,7,3,20,12,23,15,15), 3) * c (1:3)
                        )
```

I use this dataframe calculate the following GLMM:

```
large_model <- glmer (dependent ~ var_A + var_B + var_C + (1|group),
data = my_table, 
family = "poisson")
```

The r.squaredGLMM function yields the following result:

```
r.squaredGLMM (large_model)
>                 R2m       R2c
> delta     0.4171626 0.4171626
> lognormal 0.4485549 0.4485549
> trigamma  0.3824522 0.3824522
```

Now comes the interesting part. I create a function to alter the `large_model`. Within the function, I create an object containing the formula of the `large_model` via `getCall` and an object containing the family used in the `large_model`. An if-statement is then used to alter the model; here, it produces a set of (perhaps senseless) shorter models. Note, that the `the_family` - object works fine here in order to tell `glmer` which family to use. The resulting `short_model` can then also be used to calculate, for example, the resuiduals of the respective models.

```
my_function <- function (global.model = NULL, my_i = 2) {
    the_call <- getCall (global.model)
    the_family <- family (global.model)$family
    for (i in length(global.model@frame[[1]]): my_i) {
        short_model <- glmer (the_call, data = global.model@frame[2:i,], family = the_family)
        short_model_resids <- resid (short_model)
    }
}
```

This works fine:

```
my_function (global_model, 40)
```

However, when I try to pass the `short_model` to `r.squaredGLMM`, I get an error:

```
my_function <- function (global.model = NULL, my_i = 2) {
    the_call <- getCall (global.model)
    the_family <- family (global.model)$family
    for (i in length(global.model@frame[[1]]): my_i) {
        short_model <- glmer (the_call, data = global.model@frame[2:i,], family = the_family)
        short_model_resids <- resid (short_model)
        short_model_R <- r.squaredGLMM (short_model)
    }
}

my_function (global_model, 40)
> Error in glmer(formula = dependent ~ 1 + (1 | group), data = global.model@frame[2:i,  : 
> object 'the_family' not found
```

When I do it without the function and step by step by hand, it works fine (I suppose this is due to R storing `the_family` in the environment):

```
my_i <- 40
the_call <- getCall (large_model)
the_family <- family (large_model)$family
for (i in length(large_model@frame[[1]]): my_i) {
        short_model <- glmer (the_call, data = global.model@frame[2:i,], family = the_family)
        short_model_resids <- resid (short_model)
        short_model_R <- r.squaredGLMM (short_model)
    }
```

I have really no idea what is going wrong here. I hope very much, someone can help - it'd be so very good to use `r.squaredGLMM` within a function and to feed it with a family-object created within the same function.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your error. Are you using an up-to-date version of MuMIn?

Comment: Actually, updating just MuMin did not help. However, when I did an update of all packages on my machine, the error is gone. Somehow a strange behaviour, but now everything works fine.
Thank you!